# Overridden Rails Devise Methods have Empty Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have followed the instructions of overriding the devise mailer in Rails from here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

My problem is that the params for the overridden function are missing values

app/mailers/my_mailer.rb

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
   # record contains the User<ActiveRecord>
   # token = nil
   # opts = nil

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `super` in the method to get devise's default behavior.

Comment: Thanks! I was under the impression that I could simply send the email from that method without relying on the built-in devise method... Your solution works